# Different background sizes on different monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors, one 1920x1080 and one 1280x1024.
Is there a way to have my background to be stretched on my main monitor (1920x1080) and stretched on my other one so it fits completely on it. (I can post images yet, sorry for this)

OS: Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium

Comment: Lets start with important information.  What operating system are you using?  Update your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Try John's Background Switcher. There is a Mode to stretch the wallpaper across all screens.

http://johnsadventures.com/software/backgroundswitcher/